# What does this Perl script achieve?

Tags: perl

I was going over a Perl script written by someone else and I am not too familiar with Perl so could someone let me know what do the first three lines do?

```
my $ref = do($filename);
$ref != 0 or die "unable to read/parse $filename\n";
@varLines=@{$ref};
foreach $ord (@varLines)
{
    # code here
}
```

This is in the beginning of the program after the `$filename` is set with getting the commandline arguments

The format of the file being passed to this script is

```
[
  {
    "Key1" => "val1",
    "key2" => " "A",
  },
  {
    "Key3" => "val2",
    "key4" => " "B",
  },
]
```

Comment: I think this won't run. I think the `do` will clash with the `do ... while` construct.

Comment: looks like it reads the file and splits it into an array of individual lines

Comment: @Geo: no, the `do` command can also be used to "source" another perl script.

Comment: this is a production script and does run correctly

Comment: Downvote because the question does not stand on its own.

Comment: @darch:  If you think the question should be improved, don't downvote.  Suggest how you think it could be made better and those of us with sufficient rep will edit it accordingly (assuming we agree).

Comment: Noted and will adapt accordingly.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It does this:

- `my $ref = do($filename)` executes the Perl code in the file whose name is `$filename` ([ref](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.8.8/functions/do.html)) and assignes to `$ref` the value of the last command in the file
- `$ref != 0 or die …` is intended to abort if that last command in `$filename` wasn't successful (see comments below for discussion)
- `@varLines=@{$ref};` assumes that `$ref` is a reference to an array and initialises `@varLines` to the contents of that array
- `foreach $ord (@varLines) { … }` carries out some code for each of the items in the array, calling each of the `$ord` for the duration of the loop

Critically, it all depends on what is in the file whose name is in `$filename`.

Comment: Your second bullet isn't quite right.  $ref is undef if $filename could not be found or it couldn't be compiled.  The check should really be changed to "defined $ref or ...".

Answer (score 4):

The [`do`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html) command will execute the given file name as a Perl script and return the value of the last expression in the file.  So, I'm guessing the file being acted upon here returns a reference to an array.

The next block simply iterates over the elements in that returned array.

Answer (score 2):

[perldoc -f do](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/do.html)

> - **do EXPR**
>
>   Uses the value of EXPR as a filename and executes the contents of the file as a Perl script.
>
>   ```
>   do 'stat.pl';
>   ```
>
>   is just like
>
>   ```
>   eval `cat stat.pl`;
>   ```
>
>   except that it's more efficient and concise, keeps track of the current filename for error messages, searches the @INC directories, and updates `%INC` if the file is found. See ["Predefined Names" in perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#Predefined-Names) for these variables. It also differs in that code evaluated with `do FILENAME` cannot see lexicals in the enclosing scope; `eval STRING` does. It's the same, however, in that it does reparse the file every time you call it, so you probably don't want to do this inside a loop.

In this case, it appears that it is expected that the contents of `$filename` give a result of something like

```
[
  "line1",
  "line2",
  "line3",
]
```

and the `foreach` loop will then process each item.